# How to close Angular Material with Angular 2 from within a dialog

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm writing Angular app which uses [Angular-Material framework](https://material.angular.io/).
I'm presenting a [dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview), inside the component that is presented in this dialog I'm making an HTTP request to the server, when the request ends I want to close the dialog. When the dialog closes the component which invoked the dialog refresh itself.

If I'm using `md-dialog-close` the dialog closes before the processing of the HTTP request is done.

I've currently worked around this issue by using the following code when opening the dialog:

Opening the dialog

```
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(UpdateStageDialogComponent);
dialogRef.componentInstance.dialogRef = dialogRef;
```

Close the dialog from the component

```
export class UpdateStageDialogComponent implements OnInit {
  dialogRef: MdDialogRef<UpdateStageDialogComponent>;
  saveForm() {
    this.stageService.update(this.stage).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.dialogRef.close();
      },
      error => {
        alert(error);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add a reference to your component :

```
constructor(private dialogRef: MdDialogRef<yourModalComponent>) {}

functionToCallBeforeClosing() {
    this.yourService.yourHttpCall().subscribe(data => this.dialogRef.close());
}
```

Comment: Angular will inject the dialogRef?

Comment: Don't really know, I know how to use it, not how to explain it, sorry

Comment: If I had to explain, I'd say MdDialogRef is a singleton, and that Angular injects it in your component so that you can control it